# Firebase Phone Auth, Cannot receive SMS OTP on phones that does not show a 10-digit Mobile # as in getLine1Number()

Tags: firebase-authentication

Using Firebase Phone Authentication. It works well on any phone as long as the Telephony.Manager getLine1Number() returns a 10 digit mobile#.

(Not to misread that I am using getLine1Number() for firebase auth. I do not. All I am pointing is that the Firebase auth does not seem to work on phone where getLine1Number() too returns a null)

Some SIM provides in India (some with large market share) do not have this data stored and so getLine1Number() returns a null.

1. How do I get the firebase phone authentication to work with any service provider SIM in India ? - Otherwise if someone can please confirm if this is a known limitation with firebase ?

Comment: Can you tell the name of a large provider whose SIM doesn't work? That'll probably be easier to troubleshoot with, or for others to confirm if they see the same.

Comment: Also: what specifically doesn't work? Is the SMS not received on the phone? If so, what platform are you using (Android, iOS, Web)? Can you edit your question to show the code that you use to send the verification SMS? If you send the verification SMS from another platform to the same phone, does it receive it?

Comment: Thanks Frank. Reliance Jio SIM exhibits this problem. The getLine1Number() I used to narrow down the problem is on Android platform.

Comment: The android API usage example code for auth on github used as-is can show this issue. About the question "If you send the verification SMS from another platform to the same phone, does it receive it?" - Yes it does receive. This SIM where auth triggered SMS OTP does not come, infact can receive other SMS.

Comment: So are you using FirebaseUI (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) or SDK without UI? If you didn't get an error calling an API, but simply didn't receive the SMS, consider a) test with a Google voice number b) file a support ticket via https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Thanks Isabella. I am using FirebaseUI. I have tried the SDK version without UI and the results are same. I have a open ticket already and I will pursue it. About the "test with a voice number" I will do that when I get convinced that it helps the current problem. I think that may not help to know why the SMS OPT does not come. Thanks again for taking time to respond.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0' problem is resolved.